# Xcode 7 - Error trying to integrate Parse using CocoaPods (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, cocoapods, xcode7-beta2

I'm using Xcode 7 beta, and I have been trying to integrate Parse iOS SDK using Cocoapods.

I already created the `bridging-header.h`, I alreade imported Parse `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`. I already called Parse in my `AppDelegate.swift`.

The error happends when I try to use any class/object related to Parse. Actually, I'm just calling Parse with: `Parse.setApplicationId(ParseAPI.AppID, clientKey: ParseAPI.ClientKey)`

I'm getting the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for ObjectiveC.Parse in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have cleaned the project many times even a [complete clean build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998429/xcode-version-6-1-6a1030-apple-match-o-linker-error-building/25998724#25998724).

Comment: Have an exact same problem, I am just using it with cocapods

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius I thought the problem was CocoaPods or Xcode or both, but I think the problem is *Parse 1.7.5* pod. I have tried with stable environments (Xcode 6.3 and Xcode 6.4) and Parse is not working also, all the pods are working except Parse.

Answer (score 6):

Using Xcode 7 beta 4, I first migrated away from using the Objective C bridging header by removing all references to it in my XCode project.

Next, I updated my Podfile with a new line at the top:

```
use_frameworks!
```

Then I ran

```
pod outdated
```

Which told me newer versions of Parse and ParseCrashReporting were available (from 1.7.5 to 1.7.5.3).

I then ran

```
pod update
```

Opening my project in Xcode, the last step was to add import statements in files in which I was using Parse objects, so many files now included either

```
import Parse
```

or

```
import ParseCrashReporting
```

For more on use_frameworks, see http://www.innerexception.com/2015/05/cocoapods-useframeworks-means-bridging.html

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I could not solve the issue using CocoaPods.

I'm using **Xcode 7.2 beta**.

What I did is, I imported **Parse** and **Bolts** manually following the steps described in [Parse Doc](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing).

Currently, I'm having other issue. **Xcode 7** is not autocompleting anything from `bridging-header`, everything is working ok, but is not autocompleting.

*I'm not the only one having this issue* --> [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976152/xcode-7-doesnt-autocomplete-if-using-bridging-header).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a bridging header to your workspace.

Parse is written in Objective-C, so it's not the same as using the direct framework like you have done it.

Here are some steps that might help:
[enter link description here](http://www.appcoda.com/instagram-app-parse-swift/)